# Navigating 1 View Back, Then Forward To Another View (Whit animation looking like a normal push)

Tags: swift, segue, xcode11, swift5

*I'm trying to **navigate form a child viewcontroller back to it's parent viewcontrollerand then from that parent viewcontroller straight to another child viewcontroller** all by pressing one button and when this action happens, the animation needs to **seem like the child viewcontroller navigated to the other child viewcontroller but when you tap on back, it needs to navigate to the parent viewcontroller.***

I thought of 2 ways:
• 1: Navigating from one child viewcontroller to another child viewcontroller and somehow change the action that takes place when the back button is clicked to take you to the parent viewcontroller instead of the child viewcontroller. (If you know how to do this, it will give me the same results, so please please answer,)

• 2: (This is what i currently have) A delegate function in the parent that pops the current viewcontroller so it'll go back to the parent viewcontroller (this parameter is a BOOL), and after popping, navigate to the specified location. This works well! But you can still see the parent viewcontroller in this process. I just need it to look like it went directly from the one child to the other.

Additional Info:

**Imagine 3 viewscontroller:**

- VC1 (which can be seen as the parent)
- VC1.1 (a child viewcontroller of VC1)
- VC1.2 (also a child viewcontroller of VC1)

So the picture in your head should be similar to the first two layers of a tree diagram.

```
       VC 1  
        /\
       /  \
      /    \
   VC.1   VC1.2
```

**So I need VC1.1 -> VC1 -> VC1.2** But this action should seem like this happened: **VC1.1 -> VC1.2** and when you are on VC1.2 and click back, VC1 should display.

What i did:

```
    @IBAction func onAlreadyRegistered(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.navigate(to: .SIGNIN, popView: true)
    }
```

```
    func navigate(to: VC.NAVIGATIONS, popView: Bool) {
        // UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false) // Tried disabling the animation as wll
        if popView {
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: to.abs, sender: self) // abs just returns the rawValue which is the String
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
```

**This will then from the parent pop the current view controller which is the register screen, then perform seque to signin view controller**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If they are views and not viewcontrollers and you have the back button going to parent yes you can override that back button functionality to go straight to another child view.Can you show the code you currently have and what you have tried.

Comment: @SouravSachdeva it is view controllers, edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: If these controllers are managed by a navigation controller then your first idea can work.  Give VC1.2 a reference to VC1 and it can use `popToViewController` to skip back when dismissed.

Comment: So now if you are using storyboards it's a matter of segues or otherwise if you are just using code that needs to be checked. In either case you need to post your storyboard images or code method snippets.

Comment: @SouravSachdeva i added code